# I am getting an error like this while using docker but I don't know how to fix it

Tags: php, laravel, windows, docker, laradock

i'm have submit on console like this code, and I am receiving the error message below.

```
$ docker-compose up -d selenium
```

I am currently using the laravel, laradock and window10 pro.

The error does not appear on other computers and works normally, but it does not work on current computers.

Is there a way to solve it?

---

```
Starting om_selenium_1 ... error

ERROR: for om_selenium_1  Cannot start service selenium: error while creating mount source path 
'/dev/shm': mkdir /dev/shm: file exists

ERROR: for selenium  Cannot start service selenium: error while creating mount source path 
'/dev/shm': mkdir /dev/shm: file exists
```

I am currently suffering from this problem, but I would appreciate any advice

Comment: Can you show the code that makes the folder or configures the mount?

Comment: Try to launch docket-compose as administrator user.

Comment: selenium :
    build : ./selenium
    ports: 
        - "${SELENIUM_PORT}:4444"
        - "5900:5900"
    volumes:
        - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    networks:
        -frontend
        -backend

Comment: I am using Windows. What do you mean by administrator rights?

Comment: Try the [edge version](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/edge-release-notes/) of Docker for Win because [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7455) is same as your error and is [answered resolved](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7455#issuecomment-676023737) in edge version.